# Adjective-- what adjective fills those boxes

Tags: adjectives

[image]

Not sure what adjective do I fill in?

Comment: An English exam which employs *an apparel* to mean an item of clothing is inherently suspect.

Comment: This is more of a puzzle than anything about English, but the last three letters might be `-ful`.

Comment: Not sure if it answered my question. I'm really stuck with my niece's homework. :(

Comment: at first glance, I'm guessing *imported*, but it's a guessing game at best. I'm surprised that no other clues were provided, either in the form of a word list or sample text.

Comment: Thanks for the help malvolio and stoney. I think im going to refer to thesaurus for every word that anticipates expensive/elegant

Comment: This really sucks. No clues at all. Just those boxes were provided by the book

Comment: I still have one word left but I can't post it til 40 mins will pass

Comment: @Chi - I wouldn't be so sure that the word I provided is the answer - it was a guess at best, and I can find equally as many reasons not to use it.

Comment: Again, lotsaaa thanks mike! There's still one item left will post it later. Hope you could help me out again. :)

Comment: /an apparel/ is not idiomatic in English. An item of apparel would be. Apparel is an uncountable noun in English: high-end apparel; women's apparel; men's apparel; imported apparel, yes, but not /an imported apparel/ So the homework is wrong.

Comment: The answers must be at the back, it says **See Key**. If this is a school's coursebook, you should refer to the chapter that mentions clothes, for example. A list of new words and expressions are taught, and then students do a revision task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a computer search for all the 8-letter English words where the third letter had a descender (pqgyj), the sixth and eight had ascenders (lbdfht), and the other letters had neither.  I got the following words:

> acquital, aegrotat, argental, argentol, arquated, augustal, capsidal, capsuled, capuched, cryostat, engirded, engouled, enjambed, ergostat, expanded, expected, expended, experted, expiated, exported, impacted, imparled, imparted, impasted, impended, imported, imposted, ingested, injected, inparfit, inputted, keynoted, magerful, magnetod, migrated, miquelet, mujtahid, ragouted, regarded, regental, regraded, regrated, reguided, rejected, repasted, repealed, repeatal, repeated, repented, reported, reprobed, requital, requited, requoted, riposted, roqueted, sagittal, saprodil, septated, septolet, signaled, signeted, superfat, superfit, superhet, topnotch, ungaited, ungarbed, ungashed, ungirded, ungoaded, ungraded, ungrated, unguided, unguiled, ungutted, unjailed, unparfit, unparted, unpasted, unpathed, unpatted, unpealed, unpeeled, unpetted, unpitted, unpooled, unposted, unpotted, unprobed, unproded, unprofit, unpurled, unpushed, unquoted, wagonful

Of those, only *imported* really seems to fit the sentence, but I would like to see the look on the teacher's face if you supplied "superfat", "injected", or "ungirded".

*Topnotch* is on the list because `t` has a "low ascender", so it could count or not -- but I wouldn't use it because the uses the first `t` without the ascender and the second word with.